# How are the parameters of the Bernoulli distribution learned?

Tags: machine-learning, probability-distribution, weights

In the paper [Deconstructing Lottery Tickets: Zeros, Signs, and the Supermask](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.01067.pdf), they learn a mask for the network by setting up the mask parameters as $M_i = Bern(\sigma(v_i))$. Where $M$ is the parameter mask ($f(x;\theta, M) = f(x;M \odot \theta$), $Bern$ is a Bernoulli sampler, $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function, and $v_i$ is some trainable parameter.

In the paper, they learn $v_i$ using SGD. I was wondering how they managed to do that, because there isn't a reparameterization trick, as there is for some other distributions I see trained on in the literature (example: normal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from the authors of the paper.

As expected the bernoulli sampler is non-differentiable, so as an approximation they use the expectation of the samplers gradient.

$
\begin{align*}  
\frac{dL}{dv_i} &= \frac{dL}{dBern(\sigma(v_i))} * \frac{dBern(\sigma(v_i))}{d\sigma(v_i)} * \frac{d\sigma(v_i)}{dv_i} \\
&\approx \frac{dL}{dBern(\sigma(v_i))} * \frac{dE[Bern(\sigma(v_i))]}{d\sigma(v_i)} * \frac{d\sigma(v_i)}{dv_i} \\
&= \frac{dL}{dBern(\sigma(v_i))} * \frac{d\sigma(v_i)}{d\sigma(v_i)} * \frac{d\sigma(v_i)}{dv_i} \\
&= \frac{dL}{dBern(\sigma(v_i))} * 1 * \frac{d\sigma(v_i)}{dv_i} \\
\end{align*} 
$

So the answer ended up being as simple as that.